# change tableview cell content on collection view cell selection

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a `tableView` and `collectionView` in one view controller.

in `tableView` I have title description and in `collectionView` I have `lable` .

I want on `collectionView` label selection `tableView` content should change .

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Bookmark.count
    }


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionViewBookmark.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! BookMarkCollectionViewCell



    cell.lblTitle.text = Bookmark[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white



    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionViewBookmark.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
//
        let newsDict = arrNewsData[indexPath.row]

        if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {
        let cell1 = tableViewBookMark.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! BookMarkFirstTableViewCell
        cell1.lblTitle.text = newsDict["title"] as! String
        tableViewBookMark.reloadData()
        }
        tableViewBookMark.reloadData()
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableViewBookMark.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! BookMarkFirstTableViewCell

        let dict = arrNewsData[indexPath.row]


        cell.lblTitle.text = dict["title"] as! String
      // cell.imgBookMark.image = dict["image_url"]
        let url = URL(string: dict["image_url"] as! String)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if data != nil{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    cell.imgBookMark.image = image
                }
            }
        }.resume()
         return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reloading the `tableView` after updating the values in the cell,

```
tableViewBookMark.reloadData()
```

This will trigger the data source function including `cellForRowAt`, so you will lose your updated values a solution to this is to have a global variable in the `UIViewController` and check its values inside the `cellForRowAt`  and update it in the `collectionView` `DidSelect` .

**Extra tip**: you don't need to reload all the `tableView` for a single change you can use

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)
```

to reload only number of selected cells in the `tableView`

Answer (score 1):

See my inline comments.

```
var tempCell: BookMarkFirstTableViewCell?

//Inside cellForRowAt indexPath

tempCell = cell
//Inside (collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)

tempCell.lblTitle.text = newsDict["title"] as! String
```